# access parent page constant variable from user control page

Tags: c#, asp.net

can we access parent page const variables which is declare above page load, from child(User control) page load event.

```
 public const int ConstantCollection = 3;
```

Comment: Public constants generally is a bad idea. Problem with them is that they are converted into actual values at compile time. So you can create an assembly A with public constant, compile assembly B which is using this constant, and then change constant value in A. B will never receive this change unless it is recompiled. This might not be the case in your situation, but for extra safety consider using public readonly fields instead.

Comment: but i am not that security concern. its an internal project. can you guys tell me how to get this values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, if your constant is `public`.

```
<NameOfThePageClass>.<YourConstantName>
```

Constant variables behave like static variables, with the exception that you can't change them.

Since your asp.Net page is a class after all, you can access your constant as you would access it if it was in a standard class.

Example:

```
public class MyWebPage
{
    public const string myConst = "test";
}
```

to access it:

```
public void MyMethodSomewhereInAClass()
{
    this.text = MyWebPage.myConst;
}
```

Comment: I added it in the answer ;)